# passing parameters to on event callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I am missing some fundamentals of javascript events.

Can smb please explain why these two calls don't return the same result?

```
// 1
$(window).on('load', function(){
    spiderLoad();
});
```

and

```
// 2
$(window).on('load', spiderLoad);
```

**EDIT:**

```
function spiderload() {}
```

function takes no params but I use some `$jQuery` to get values from `data`, `href`...etc. I am suspecting that I am losing the load event object reference, when calling spiderLoad as in `1`.

Thanks

Comment: Are they supposed to return someting at all? If so what?

Comment: They should behave indentical as far as what they do. Please elaborate what you mean by "donT return the same result"

Comment: The first one calls `spiderLoad()` with no arguments, the second one will call `spiderLoad()` with the arguments that the `load` event will pass.

Comment: @Johan - well, not really, referencing the function will pass the arguments, in this case the event, and set the value of `this` etc.

Comment: @robertklep that s what i m suspecting.. but what are they?

Comment: Why not post the function, and we'll tell you ?

Comment: @Zortkun The arguments are [documented with `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) -- **handler** Type: Function( [Event](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event) eventObject \[, [Anything](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Anything) extraParameter ] [, ... ] ). Also, below that within the description, "*When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered;*"

Answer (score 4):

They have different results because they are doing fundamentally different things.

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    spiderLoad();
});
```

This creates a new, anonymous function and adds it as a event handler. The anonymous function calls `spiderLoad()` with no arguments.

```
$(window).on('load', spiderLoad);
```

This adds `spiderLoad()` as *directly* as an event handler, meaning it will receive a [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) as its first parameter.

EDIT: if `spiderLoad()` takes no arguments, there there *should* be no difference, except perhaps value of `this` inside `spiderLoad()`

Comment: that s it. i have a line : var href = $(this).attr("href")  that fails apparently.

Comment: I believe the value of `this` for event handlers is the element the event fired on, which should be `window` for the second (unless jQuery special-cases handler attached to `window`, which it might).

Answer (score 2):

If spiderLoad is returning a value, they will act differently.

```
function spiderLoad(){
    return false
}
```

They would be the same (assuming the function doesn't care what arguments are passed in) if it was written like this.

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    return spiderLoad();
});
```